# Htaccess - how to get 'subfolder' value. Please see example

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

If the website url is `www.domain.com/subfolder/sitecontent`, then how do I update the `.htaccess` file below so that all the requests go to `/subfolder/index.php` instead of `/index.php` . I know I can manually add `/subfolder/` but I need it to be dynamic. Is it possible?

Basically I intend to use the same htaccess and same set of files on 2-3 different URLs on the same server. e.g. one is `www.domain2.com/sitecontent` (no subfolder here). All these URLs point to the same site. Any help will be appreciated.

This is how my current `.htaccess` file looks like. It's located at `/subfolder/.htaccess` for domain1 or `/` for 2nd domain example.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    #http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder 
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder 
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file, 
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the 
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't know if catched what you need at all, but i think you just need to append the folder name, can you try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    #http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /subfolder

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder 
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder 
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file, 
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the 
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hmmm ... actually I have another thought after posting this question. I am thinking of accessing the site by creating sub-domains (which is a bit painful as I don't have direct control) rather than /subfolders. I am doing with subfolders here mainly as test/staging environment. I will test the above and let you know how it goes. thx

Comment: np, anyway sub-domains needs sub-folders or i'm mistaking?

Comment: No - sub-domains won't need sub-folders. Basically, current setup sends all requests to `/` where index.php takes care of it. But as this index.php isn't there (it's in sub-folder) so it's not working. That's why I posted the question here.

Comment: I just updated `RewriteBase /` to `RewriteBase /subfolder` it seems to be working... still doing more testing.